# Serach Node using Query Builder In AEM?

Tags: aem, query-builder

i need to get some asset node use Query Builder How I search i am gving folder path

```
1 :/content/dam/assets/en_us/myDatas/c02442188
2: /content/dam/assets/en_us/myDatas/c02442189
3: /content/dam/assets/ar_sa/myDatas/c02442170
4: /content/dam/assets/spanish/myDatas/c02442171
5: /content/dam/assets/spanish/B/c02442172
```

from thse asset

i need to get only 1,2,3,4
which means 'myDatas' folder contains. 
need to get this nodes using query builder

### i started query builder like this

```
path=/content/dam/assets
type=sling:Folder
```

Answer (score 0):

path=/content/dam/assets

type=sling:Folder

nodename=myDatas*